# Pegar um paramêtro da URL com JQuery

Tags: jquery

Bom dia a todos, tenho uma dúvida.
Tenho essa URL: 
http://localhost/admin-ativo.com/public/evento/edit4/id_menu/8/id_evento/22054

como posso pegar o parâmetro **22054** que está nessa URL e atribuir a uma variavel no JQuery ?

Comment: dá uma sacada nesse link https://stackoverflow.com/a/21903119/4551469

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que o elemento que você queira capturar sempre esteja no **final** da URL, você pode fazer assim:

```
var url = 'http://localhost/admin-ativo.com/public/evento/edit4/id_menu/8/id_evento/22054'.split('/');

var last = url.pop();

console.log(last); // 22054
```